# Angular2 systemjs.config.js ' "ReferenceError: System is not defined"

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have read all the other posts with this identical issue, but haven't been able to resolve the problem.

If I compile to javascript in the browser, I get two 404 errors for @angular/http and @angular/core.

When I set the config file to transpile first, I get a compilation error in system.config.js:

'ReferenceError: System is not defined' at this line

```
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
```

I started the project from the quick-start guide and Tour of Heros Http sample.

After comparing all my files against those in the quick-start, I went through and copied the quick start files into my project.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but have hit a dead end. 
FYI: I am new to Angular and Angular2. Using WebStorm to develop and compile.

Here is the index.html and systemjs.config.js

```js
//system.config.js
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Generic Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="forms.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Edit: This is the point in my http-service.component.ts file where I receive the 404 errors:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular2/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Please let me know what other files will help. I appreciate any insight!

Comment: Do you see the js files in your directory? how do you build the project?

Comment: I can see http and core in the node_modules/@angular folder.

Comment: I'm using SystemJS to bundle things and I'm just (building?) running it from WebStorm

Comment: which version of angular 2 are you using? beta version of angular used 'angular2' on the imports where current rc version use '@angular' - fairly sure this is where your error is

Comment: in my packages I have mostly "2.0.0-rc.3" (for common, compiler, core, http, platform-browser etc).

Comment: @Jarod Moser: Yes! Thank you I knew it was something simple. I had edited and used both "@angular2 "instead of "@angular"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current versions of angular 2 use '@angular' instead of what beta was using 'angular2'

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```